# Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed in php mailer( https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Here is code for sending email from localhost after i referred a lot from online.

html form:

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
  Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

email.php:

```
<?php

// $email and $message are the data that is being
// posted to this page from our html contact form
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body='hellooooo';
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // specify main and backup server

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication

$mail->Username = "xxxx@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "zzz"; // SMTP password
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mailer->Port = 465;//587;
$mail->AddAddress("xxx", "xx");
$mail->SetFrom('xxx@gmail.com','xxxx');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "You have received feedback from your website!";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

so when i run my code it shows error like this,

> Message could not be sent.
>
> Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

And i removed semicolon in this line `;extension=php_openssl.dll` from the following files, and restart the xampp.

```
c/xampp/apache/bin/php.ini and c/xampp/php/php.ini
```

still stays same error..

**Note:** I m new to php, but i want to know particular this one and fix the problem. and I referred similar questions in stack, but it didn't help me,

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: thanks for your edit, i forgot to remove password..

Comment: Never ever expose your username and password !! It requires a second to hijack your account mate.

Comment: @Maverick: I already did ,, what your above link explained.. still i have same error..

Comment: If you edit your `php.ini` don't forget to restart your xampp

Comment: make sure you are not caught in Firewall? if any???

Comment: I believe that you're referring the correct path for the files you include...

Comment: what do you mean, @Avinash: I can't understand

Comment: so may i know, what is the correct path,, Now all the files in my system c/xampp/htdocs/somefoldername/index.html

Comment: @saina If you are having firewall installed in your network then make sure that firewall allows you to connect to your SMTP host

Comment: How can i check, whether firewall connect or not?

Comment: have you tried SMTPSecure as tls..i mean $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  if not just try this

Comment: Did you actually read the troubleshooting guide that the error linked to? You need to enable debug output and show what it says, everything else is just guessing.

Comment: thanks for your comment @Synchro: I can't able to understand that guide because I m new to php.. if you can.. please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your credentials for connecting to your authentication has failed. I often send mail from my local and I found it that it's a LOT easier to use another SMTP than gmail, like [mandrillapp](https://mandrillapp.com/login/?referrer=%2F), free until 12,000 mails. There are a lot of things that I don't understand in your code so I will share mine.

```
<?php 

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'your@username.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mandrilapp_will_give_you_a_password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'your@email.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Test phpmailer';
$mail->addAddress('who_are_you_sending@to.com');               // Name is optional

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Be sure to have PHPMailer-master folder (you can download it from [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)) at the same level as your php file. This is how I link phpmailer. Hope it helps, if you have any questions, ask me!

Comment: The only file you need is this one : PHPMailerAutoload.php. This file will autoload every file you need.

Comment: Did you sign up to mandrillapp and put your credentials (username, password) according to your account? Don't forget to active a API key, which is your password. The only thing to change in my code is Username, Password and addAddress to your recipient (test with your own e-mail)

Comment: Sure, it's because I never get it work with gmail smtp. I had same problem as you, so I tried mandrillapp which is free until you send 12,000 mails and give you a smtp, username and password. It's working great to test mails on local.

Comment: When you are in mandrillapp, go in settings, click on "new API key", then put it to "on" or activate, whatever it is, and your API key is your password to put in $mail->Password = 'you_api_key';

Comment: hi ..@Matthieu Boisjoli...